# Render each Objects in an array in HTML from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I have a JavaScript array of objects taken from a JSON file. Each object in the array represents a product. The following code shows the JavaScript. The `console.log` displays each element in the console, however the innerHTML only renders the last as this is the last value to be rendered.

```
/* global $ */
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var products = [];

$.getJSON('/products', function(data){
    output.innerHTML = data


    for(var keys in data){
        console.log(data[keys]);
        products.push(data[keys]);
        output.innerHTML = data[keys].NAME;
    }
    // output.innerHTML = products;
    //console.log(products)

});
```

I want each product to be rendered in it's own output div. How would I display each element in the HTML instead of just the last?

Comment: note it is generally bad practice to use `for in ` on arrays

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just append the element to your output. Actually you did it.

Change this:

```
output.innerHTML = data[keys].NAME;
```

To this:

```
$('#output').append(`<div>${data[keys].NAME}</div>`);
```

So:

```
for(var keys in data){
        console.log(data[keys]);
        products.push(data[keys]);
        $('#output').append(`<div>${data[keys].NAME}</div>`);
    }
```

I would recommend you also to change the `for...in` with a simple `forEach`, so  to change the loop into this:

```
data.forEach((el) => {
  products.push(el);
  $('#output').append(`<div>${el.NAME}</div>`);
});
```

The error in your code was just that you were overriding the HTML content of your element every time. If you change:

```
output.innerHTML = data[keys].NAME;
```

to this:

```
output.innerHTML += data[keys].NAME;
```

It should already work

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery "append". You dont need to make product object.

Try like this:

```
for(var keys in data){
    $(".productList").append( "<div>"+data[keys].NAME+"</div>" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your `output` element should be a wrapper containing other elements repeated for each product. One semantic option is to use a list, such as `ul` + `li`.

You should iterate your products and append its piece of HTML to an array. When you are done processing them, you assign that chunk of HTML to the `output` element.

```js
// Just to keep your code untouched:

const $ = {
  getJSON(url, callback) {
    callback([{
      ID: 1,
      NAME: 'Product 1',
      PRICE: '2.50',
    }, {
      ID: 2,
      NAME: 'Product 2',
      PRICE: '1.25',
    }, {
      ID: 3,
      NAME: 'Product 3',
      PRICE: '10.00',
    }]);
  },
};

const output = document.getElementById('output');

let productsArray = [];

$.getJSON('/products', function(products){
  productsArray = products;

  output.innerHTML = products.map(product => {  
    return `<li data-id="${ product.ID }">
      <span>${ product.NAME }</span>
      <span>${ product.PRICE }</span>
    </li>`;
  }).join('');
});
```

```html
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#output').append(`<div>${data[keys].NAME}</div>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

In reference to @VK321, you can also use the `.map` method.

```
data.map(element => {
  $(".productList").append( `<div>${element.NAME}</div>` );
})
```